# Filename Completion for Remote Files

Tags: autocompletion, filesystem

My friend showed me a cool trick on Emacs some days ago where he could just open a file on a remote server and I instantly thought "there should be a way to do that in vim too" and it was true.

I can just use `:e scp://user@server//filepath` to do that, no problem ;). However, he could just type the server name and then get completion for file paths and names (with tab), something that I haven't been able to do. Does somebody know if this can be done in vim?

Comment: I'd have though ctrlp might support it... but apparently it's a [feature request](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/629).

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, but **currently**(2015) not out-of-the-box, because the built-in file-manager of vim doesn't natively support remote browsing. .

Update Q3@2016:

There are several work-arounds, with varying degrees of comfort/compatibility/effort. All together they add up to a nice solution, but they can all also be used individually:

- **Setup a user-level `afuse`/`sshfs` daemon in your shell init files**

  With a few lines of script sourced from e.g. `.profile`, you can setup an on-demand auto-mounter under a directory e.g. `~/scp/`. [Details of this integration in a post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294965/127903) on [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com). This is the most comfortable option, remote files "appear" local, but requires `afuse` and `sshfs` to be available to you.
- **Setup shell command line completion for remote file paths**

  The completion function package for bash has a few functions designed for `ssh` and `scp` completion. [With a wrapper function `vim()`, mangling remote paths into `vim`'s expected form, they can be used to supply TAB-completed remote files to `vim`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294834/127903). The minor shortcomings of this approach are also detailed there. For situations without afuse. Needs `bash-completion` to be installed, or equivalent and adaptations for other shells.

If you can't modify your environment or `.vimrc`-only: In the vim file-manager you can use the <kbd>/</kbd>/<kbd>?</kbd> Keys to search forwards/backwards, and you could map <kbd>TAB</kbd> to one of them. This is more powerful than it sounds for quickly navigating you around the file-system. Description below.

## Basic Workaround (for standard vim with NetRW):

- Don't point vim to a remote file
- Point to a directory "at the top" e.g. `$HOME`: `vim scp://files/`, or `/`: `vim scp://files///`
- NetRW plugin opens in wanted top-level-folder (`/` or `$HOME`).
- In NetRW, you can navigate with surprisingly few keystrokes:
- To edit remote `/etc/network/interfaces` with NetRW on `/`:

  <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>et</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>netw</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>int</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

You can always use `?` to search back upwards, without wrapping from the top.

**Even better**, for **nearly mimicking** <kbd>TAB</kbd>-Completion add in `.vimrc`:

- Map <kbd>TAB</kbd> to <kbd>/</kbd>  in NetRW: `autocmd filetype netrw noremap <buffer> <TAB> /`
- Configure NetRW for TreeView: `let g:netrw_liststyle=3`
- [Add a toggle for a remote VExplore for `<C-E>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5636941/5208540), if you want (I use it).
- I also recommend `incsearch`, `ignorecase` and `smartcase` for NetRW, or all buffers.

Compared to "conventional" tab-completion, the above is different, yet very comfortable.

Note: All of the above assumes ssh certificate based password-less connections in [`~/.ssh/config`](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) with User, Port, Compression, JumpHost (ProxyCommand are setup up such that only hostname/aliases are needed.

<sub>This has also been previously discussed offsite
[here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/pikbl/is_there_a_way_to_get_tabcompletion_for_vim_over/)
and [here](http://thomer.com/howtos/netrw_completion.html)</sub>

Comment: Can you expand on the trick by summarizing the link? A plain link is not very useful if the site goes down or dies.

Comment: I think, this is more or less my final "solution", until NetRW can do this natively. I will still take care of remaining known issues, but expect to find (or be pointed to) more subtle bugs, fixes, and enhancements. They will be addressed/incorporated. Thank you for commenting.