# NetRW bug? : vim scp://host1/filepath scp://host2/otherfilepath only opens first file

Tags: netrw

There is some strange behavior to observe in the current version of NetRW shipped with Debian Jessie (current as of Mid-2015) on my installation. Searching online doesn't immediately reveal other reports, or a known bug/existing patch. I'm currently not yet excluding my environments, or that this is documented behavior. Haven't found that yet though.

When I attempt to open 2 or more files with vim on different remote servers, only the first one gets opened successfully, concerning the other(s) I get a [New Directory] message. I switch command-line parameter sequence, the other one opens successfully.

Example:

`vim scp://host1/filepath1 scp://host2/otherfilepath2`
==> First file opens, but second file is blank

`vim scp://host2/otherfilepath2 scp://host1/filepath1`
==> Behavior consistent: Opening other files than first fails.

On top of it, **both fail**, if I also specify a local file first:

`vim local/fi.le scp://host2/otherfilepath2 scp://host1/filepath1`

Following variant at least opens the first scp-file and the local file:

`vim scp://host2/otherfilepath2 local/fi.le scp://host1/filepath1`

[Running with all local customizations disabled as described in detail here:](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/3102) `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N scp...` creates buffers for all files, but all remote file buffers are empty.

I stumbled upon this, when I was testing some edge cases in a [solution/hack I was proposing as an answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4243/3102)
to a question about
[Filename Completion for Remote Files](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3943/3102)

Comment: I don't see this behavior. I tried both vim local scp://... and two scp://...s . Have you tried upgrading your netrw? Its up to v155d now.
(http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW)

Comment: Can you still reproduce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been solved in the meantime, as of at least v155.

The errant behavior does not occur anymore. All remote files are opened correctly.